# dynamic textbox for user information in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am developing one travel website using PHP,where user can book the travel. While booking I am storing the name and age of the user.

And I have one filed top of this to describe how many people are travelling ,based on this field I need name and age input text box dynamically .

How to do this ? any useful help ?

Comment: have you tied any?pls show what you tried

Comment: not getting what you are trying to say - "I have one filed top of this to describe how many people are travelling ,based on this field I need name and age input text box dynamically "

Comment: i have one field to user to enter how many of traveling (ex :3) . at the same time that much of text box has to create dynamically .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting sample code which may help you. You might have to modify it according to your need to use.

The **HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="numPpl" name="numPpl">
<br><br>
<div id="demo">

</div>
```

The **JQuery**

```
<script>
    $('#numPpl').blur(function()
    {
        for(i=1; i<=$('#numPpl').val(); i++)
        {
            $('#demo').append('<input type="text"><br><input type="text"><br><br>');
        }
    });
</script>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ovoqnr2n/)